# Ansible install from source - hacking/env-setup fails

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to install ansible from source. I have done:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
sudo pip install paramiko PyYAML Jinja2 httplib2
git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive
```

Then, when I try

```
~/src/ansible$ source ./hacking/env-setup
```

I get

```
: command not found
: command not found
bash: ./hacking/env-setup: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
'ash: ./hacking/env-setup: line 17: `elif [ $(basename -- "$0") = "env-setup" ]; then
```

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: Hm, it works for me with a fresh clone. I also don't get the `: command not found` entries, and the script doesn't use `:` as a command - does something in your environment do that?

Comment: I'm just wondering if it's wrong shell or some Python issue. I'm on Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you happen to have dos line endings in your env-setup? Check your core.autocrlf setting, that should not be true. If it is, do:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```